# geometry-quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

In the following figure, we have two right triangles, ABC and BDC.  Knowing that triangle BDC is isosceles (BD=DC) show that the measure of angle DAC is 45 degrees.[image]

I'm not even sure where to start with this one.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trace the circle whose diameter is the common hypothenuse $BC$. The angles $BAD$ and $DAC$ are both on this circumference and correspond to chords that have equal length ($BD$ and $CD$), so they are equal. Since their sum is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, they both have to be $\frac{\pi}{4}$.